Install Package in Chroot. Script running outside Chroot
I am trying to do a kind of analyzer. To do that I need to work with different distributions I decided on trying chroot. What im trying to do is,

using a python script on main machine
Go into chroot context
Run apt-get install in chroot context
Repeat this for a list of packages.

I have checked out pychroot. It basically works as context manager.
However, when I enter into Chroot context and run apt-get install. The script execution freezes. When I check the Chroot, I find that the package is installed. But I end up killing processes eventually.
Below, you can find a simplified example of code that freezes:
with Chroot(path) as chroot:
      subprocess.run(installation_command)

When strace the frozen apt-get subprocess, I get the following output:
(.venv) user@server:$ ps aux | grep apt
root     2797755  0.4  0.1  62656 53380 pts/17   T    08:58   0:00 apt-get install -y bluez-dbg
fatih.d+ 2798237  0.0  0.0   8964   656 pts/16   R+   09:00   0:00 grep --color=auto apt
(.venv) user@server:$ sudo strace -p 2797755
strace: Process 2797755 attached
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---

(.venv) user@server:$ ps aux | grep python
root     2797660  0.2  0.4 339364 133848 pts/17  S    08:58   0:01 python test.py
root     2797740  0.0  0.3 339364 101696 pts/17  S    08:58   0:00 python test.py
root     2797746  0.0  0.3 339364 101400 pts/17  S    08:58   0:00 python test.py
root     2797749  0.0  0.3 339364 102344 pts/17  T    08:58   0:00 python test.py

(.venv) user@server:$ sudo strace -p 2797660
strace: Process 2797660 attached
read(7, ^Cstrace: Process 2797660 detached
 <detached ...>

(.venv) user@server:$ sudo strace -p 2797740
strace: Process 2797740 attached
wait4(-1, ^Cstrace: Process 2797740 detached
 <detached ...>

(.venv) user@server:$ sudo strace -p 2797746
strace: Process 2797746 attached
wait4(-1, ^Cstrace: Process 2797746 detached
 <detached ...>

(.venv) user@server:$ sudo strace -p 2797749
strace: Process 2797749 attached
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
^Cstrace: Process 2797749 detached


This is a place where syscall tracing tools are appropriate. "Freezes" is too broad to be answerable. If you use strace and it tells you which syscall is hanging, that's a narrower, more specific topic to investigate. (Note that it may well be that what you have is something like a child process that got spawned, inherited a file descriptor on a FIFO from the installation command, and is preventing the other end of that descriptor from being closed... but whatever it is, you're going to need to do some investigation work to run it down).

Hi Im not very familiar with strace. So I have run it on the process and added it to my question

Okay, so one read() from file descriptor 7 (you'll need to look at what FD 7 is connected to to understand why that's hanging), and then a bunch of waiting for child processes to finish (you'd want to look at what the child processes of those PIDs actually are). Which is to say -- strace gave you places to start investigating, but you need to do the work of that investigation (in an environment where the program is still running and the identifiers are still valid).

Mind, the other thing happening is SIGTTOU -- that happens when a program is trying to write to a terminal where it isn't the foreground process. In general, a good place to start towards fixing that is redirecting stdin, stdout and stderr when you start your process so none of them point to the terminal at all -- redirect stdin from /dev/null if you don't expect any input to be needed, redirect stdout and stderr to a pipe that your Python program reads, etc.

So making it subprocess.run(installation_command, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, capture_output=True) might be a place to start. (You'll need to save the process object so you can actually inspect that captured output). Also, if the specific installation command in use is something that has noninteractive modes (the ability to turn off prompting &c), that's an appropriate step to take.

Okay thank you very much for the feedback. Im working on it
